# Need to use widget into ionic 3 app pages

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, widget

I have to include external widget into my ionic page. This is working when I add script into my index.html and using widget html element into first loading page(Ex Home.html) but not working in other pages.
I have developed app using ionic 3. I need to display FXStreet’s Economic Calendar Pro widget into my application globaldata.html. For this I have done as like below, I have added this code into my src/index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var fxcalendar_config = {
            host: "http://calendar.fxstreet.com",
            css: 'mini',
            rows: 7,
            pastevents: 0,
            hoursbefore: 1,        
            timezone: 'India Standard Time',
            showcountryname: 'true',
            columns: 'date,time,country,event,previous,volatility,actual',
            isfree: 'true',
            countrycode: 'JP:EMU,UK,US',
            culture:'en-US'
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://calendar.fxstreet.com/scripts/mini"></script>
```

And added the below code into src/pages/globaldata/globaldata.html

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
        <div id="fxst_calendar" class="last-table" style="position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: auto; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
    </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
```

Could you please help anyone to solve this issue. This is working in ionic 1 application, not working in ionic 3 apps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution like below, this is working without issue.
In the constructor of the page I have added the code as below,

```
let scripttagElement = document.createElement('script');
scripttagElement.src = "http://calendar.fxstreet.com/scripts/mini";
document.body.appendChild(scripttagElement);
```

so working in the page.